# How to send Alert SMS to multiple numbers and collect response using Twilio Studio and Functions

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Alert is originally generated by external system and it is routed to Twilio (incoming SMS message). Twilio provides smart, prioritized SMS alerting for group of receivers. I have used Twilio Studio to implement the basic flow.

In the beginning, there is only a few numbers on receiver list and each  of them is receiving an SMS, that is send by Twilio flow (I have used Twilio functions to send these outbound SMS messages) . If any receiver accepts to handle alert root cause (by pressing 1) the system logs the data, distributes that information to other on receiver list and stops repeating alerts. If receiver skips the alert (by pressing 2), the system logs the information and does not send any more alerts for this specific receiver. If there is no reply at all or if answering receivers have only selected 2 (skipping), the system increases new numbers to group of receivers and repeats the alert distribution (except numbers that have skipped). This is done a few times in configurable interval e.g. 10mins or until alert is accepted by some of the receivers. Group of receivers may be increased in all rounds.  In the end, summary message is sent to all receivers (e.g. alert not accepted/number XXX accepted).

So my problems are 1.) how to collect answers (accept/skipped) from received SMS messages and 2.) how to implement that 10min pause to Twilio flow.

For problems, I'm thinking of following options:

- By using Twilio Functions call from Studio flow, read all inbound message resources from Programmable SMS API. "inbound messages received during last hour, to my TwilioNumber, and from receiver that belong to list of receivers" and figure out then message by message, what belong to this flow? Is there anywhere an example how that is done?
- Maybe it would be possible to pass each outbound SMS message through REST API back to Studio Flow and use "Send and Wait for Reply" widget - If this would be possible it would solve also the next problem pausing/delaying the studio flow.
- How to stop/delay studio flow execution after each SMS group message has been send, e.g. for 10 minutes (or until someone accepts the alert by replying with "1"). Can I do it inside Studio flow, is there pause/wait function somewhere. Or should the delay be implemented otherwise. Any examples, how it is done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear on the flow. You state, `triggered by incoming message` but it sounds like an outbound alert case. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve at a higher level rather then how you are trying to achieve it?

Comment: Alan, Thanks for your reply. I rewrote the description of the case. I hope it is now more clear.